# A cursor with the name 'MY_CURSOR' already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I try to get data by cursor such as below code but get error that :

> A cursor with the name 'MY_CURSOR' already exists.

I search and found out that I should use `LOCAL` word  in definition of cursor such as     `DECLARE MY_CURSOR LOCAL CURSOR`  but get error again that

> Invalid usage of the option local in the DECLARE CURSOR statement.

How can i fix this?

```
DECLARE @tag AS NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @tempTbl AS TABLE (tagcol NVARCHAR(1000))
DECLARE MY_CURSOR LOCAL CURSOR 
FOR
    SELECT bt.Tag
    FROM   BlogTable AS bt
    WHERE  bt.IsEnglish = 0
           AND bt.IsActive = 1
           AND bt.IsDelete = 0

OPEN MY_CURSOR   
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @tag
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTbl
    SELECT *
    FROM   dbo.FunSpliteStr(@tag, '،') 

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @tag
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

SELECT tagcol
FROM   @tempTbl AS tt
GROUP BY
       tt.tagcol
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Your query does not really required the use of cursor.

Comment: I add DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR but don't solved

Comment: I agree with @Squirrel here, there's no need for a cursor here; this can be achieved without one. Why are you using one, programmer138200?

Comment: I have tag field In all records that contains string such as "00,11,22,33" and I should split this values by , charachter  and then select all. I should use FunSpliteStr function for this . Are you have another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: It's also a way of doing that

```
DECLARE @tag AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @tag = COALESCE(@tag + ',', '') + bt.Tag
FROM   BlogTable AS bt
WHERE  bt.IsEnglish = 0
        AND bt.IsActive = 1
        AND bt.IsDelete = 0

SELECT *
FROM dbo.FunSpliteStr(@tag, '،')
```

Answer (score 3):

While everybody is right in saying you don't need a cursor here (and therefore you shouldn't use it), in answer to your actual question: You should specify LOCAL|GLOBAL after `CURSOR` keyword:

```
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL
```

Comment: Thanks, This is just the expected response

Answer (score 2):

non cursor query

```
SELECT *
FROM   BlogTable AS bt
       CROSS APPLY dbo.FunSpliteStr(bt.Tag, '،') 
WHERE  bt.IsEnglish = 0
       AND bt.IsActive = 1
       AND bt.IsDelete = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment from Larnu above.  I'd remove the cursor above and use cross apply instead.   Give the following a look.

```
SELECT
  bt.Tag,
  *
FROM BlogTable AS bt
CROSS APPLY dbo.FunSpliteStr(bt.Tag, '،') FS
WHERE bt.IsEnglish = 0
AND bt.IsActive = 1
AND bt.IsDelete = 0
```

If you still feel you "need" a cursor try running the close and deallocate statements separately first and then try running your while query again.